# Odd page behaviour after removing sidebar

Tags: php, templates

One of my web pages is displaying odd behaviour, after selecting a no sidebar template for the page. The sidebar has disappeared, but elements within the sidebar, now show in the bottom right-hand corner of the page

Here is the PHP for the no sidebar template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page without sidebar
*/
?>

<?php
global $inove_nosidebar;
$inove_nosidebar = true;
include('page.php');
?>
```

Here is a link to a image of the how the page looks at present.
http://www.thedash.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Sidebar.jpg

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're including page.php in here - does that have the get_sidebar() call in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code validator at http://validator.w3.org/ to find and fix a missing closing `</div>` tag or other html errors that are causing the display problem.